# Cannot match exactly one occurence using regex

Tags: r

How do I match exactly one occurrence of braced content?

```
grep(x=c(1223,12,1), pattern="{0-9}{3}", value=T)
```

yields:

```
"1223" "12"   "1"
```

Why don't I get only the last part of as a result of this:

```
grep(x=c(1223,12,1), pattern="{0-9}{1}", value=T)
```

instead I got the same:

```
"1223" "12"   "1"
```

And what if the length is more than one, let's say that I need:

```
> grep(value=T,x=c('A1B','A12B'),"[0-9]{1}")
```

To give me only the first part of x (get the word with exactly one number in it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For exact matching, you need to use anchors. And also it must be `[0-9]` not `{0-9}`, note the brackets used.

```
grep(x=c(1223,12,1),pattern="^[0-9]{1}$",value=T)
# [1] "1"
grep(x=c(1223,12,1),pattern="[0-9]{3}",value=T)
# [1] "1223"
grep(x=c(1223,12,1),pattern="^[0-9]{3}$",value=T)
#character(0)
```

last one returns nothing because there isn't a number which exactly contain three digits.

Comment: Than you, I need to match the word that contains exactly one number anywhere in it.

Comment: you mean exactly one digit?

Comment: try `grep(x=c(1223,12,1),pattern="^\\D*\\d\\D*$",value=T)`

Comment: OK that's right!!! Thanks a lot. It comes to my mind the last I would eventually need. What if a string begins on a digit? If I use `\D` I could not match the string like `1ASD`... How to check that?

Comment: `^\d`  to check if a string begins with a  digit or not. `\D` matches any char but not a digit char.